# How to initialised complex array in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use variable which is as below:

`var Storage: { Id: string; Sequence: string[]; } =???`

without initializing if I am trying to use it is throwing undefined/null exception. How to initialized the above? I tried something like:

`var Storage: { Id: string; Sequence: string[]; } = {null;[]};`

But no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var storage: { Id: string; Sequence: string[]; } = { Id: null, Sequence: [] };
```

Comment: tried above but getting below error: Error 1 Cannot convert '{}' to '{ Id: string; Sequence: string[]; }': Type '{}' is missing property 'Id' from type '{ Id: string; Sequence: string[]; }'

Comment: Ooops. Sorry about that. I fixed my answer. I typed `=` instead of `:`